# Combining categorical columns in R

Tags: r

I have two columns in R which I would like to combine. One contains categorical variables which state if an individual is on medication for HTN and the other contains categorical variables as well which state if an individual has HTN (measured). The categorical variables are 0 and 1, so the final vector would have to give 1 if its in either or both of the previous ones.

Do you have any ideas of an easy way to do that ?

Comment: `as.integer(rowSums(df) > 0L)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, df1)
#[1] 1 0 1 1 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1=c(0, 0,1, 1, 0), v2=c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming a dataframe and numeric values:

```
apply(df,1,function(x)sum(sum(x>0)>0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$newCol <- ifelse(as.numeric(as.character(col1)) == 0 & as.numeric(as.character(col2))== 0, 0, 1)
```